# Reaction Rates & Equilibrium

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

So I have a quick question about some concept I have watched in a video, it is illustrated as follows.

$$\ce{A + B <=> C + D}$$

So what the video is saying is that if you increase $\ce{A}$ then you get the products to **increase** and the $\ce{C + D}$ to **increase** as well.

My question is that shouldn't the products also depend on the $\ce{B}$ and not only just the $\ce{A}$. So to increase the **products** don't we need to increase both the **reactants**?

Here's [the video for reference](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/reaction-rates/v/le-chatelier-s-principle).